# Configuring my Linux firewall for Tomcat

Tags: linux, firewall, tomcat, iptables

I'm following some instructions for [Installing Tomcat](http://www.linux.org/docs/ldp/howto/MMBase-Inst-HOWTO/x321.html). They require me to add the following line to my iptables file:

```
-A RH-Lokkit-0-50-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Having carefully read the man page for iptables, I have learned what the parameters do, except for the first one.

What does -A RH-Lokkit-0-50-INPUT do, and can you confirm that it is sensible in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-A RH-Lokkit-0-50-INPUT` is adding it to the chain named `RH-Lokkit-0-50-INPUT`.  Unless that chain exists, I would not use it.

You can see your existing rules with:

`iptables -L -n`

If you do not have the chain, you can simply use the following in its place:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 --syn -j ACCEPT`

If you do not have firewall rules setup in the first place, this rule is superfluous.

Comment: Many thanks, Warner. Doing what you suggested has worked.